# Image downloading with progress using AlamofireImage?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofireimage

Is there any way to download an image using AlamofireImage and get some kind of feedback about the download progress while leveraging the power of it's **UIImage Extensions, Image Filters and Image Cache**?

I know I can fallback to a plain `Alamofire.request` + `responseImage` but I'd like to keep things simple and make use of the **UIImageView Extension**.

Thank you!

Comment: Use this: https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage

Comment: @LokeshDudhat the question is related to AlamofireImage. I'm already using it but I can't find a way to track the download progress of the image…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not any way at the moment to use AlamofireImage alongside the `UIImageView` extension to receive progress updates when downloading an image. The reason it wasn't added initially was that it didn't seem like the majority of users would need such a feature. I would love to discuss more to see if this is a feature that we'd actually like to add to AlamofireImage in a future release.

Would you be willing to open up an issue walking through your use case? I would just like to know exactly how you would expect it to work and why you actually need the progress reporting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @cnoon! I've just posted an issue https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage/issues/48 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this with Swift 3.0.2:

```
let utilityQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)
let url = "http://kingofwallpapers.com/code/code-006.jpg"

    Alamofire.download(url)
        .downloadProgress(queue: utilityQueue) { progress in
            print("Download Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
        }
        .responseData { response in
            print("Response is \(response)")
            if let data = response.result.value {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Alamofire download image with process

Downloading a File w/Progress

```
Alamofire.download(.GET, "url...", destination: destination)
         .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
             print(totalBytesRead)

             // This closure is NOT called on the main queue for performance
             // reasons. To update your ui, dispatch to the main queue.
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                 print("Total bytes read on main queue: \(totalBytesRead)")
             }
         }
         .response { _, _, _, error in
             if let error = error {
                 print("Failed with error: \(error)")
             } else {
                 print("Downloaded file successfully")
             }
         }
```

Comment: As I said in my original post, *«I know I can fallback to a plain Alamofire.request + responseImage but I'd like to keep things simple and make use of the UIImageView Extension»*. This is in order to take advantage of caching and other helpful functionalities.