# How to use AlamofireImage ProgressHandler

Tags: swift, alamofireimage

Im having a hard to figuring out how exactly I can define the `ProgressHandler` parameter. The `typealias` is defined as`public typealias ProgressHandler = (bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalExpectedBytes: Int64) -> Void`
 More information can be found here https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage/pull/91

```
let URLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://httpbin.org/image/jpeg")!)
    ImageDownloader().downloadImages(URLRequests: [URLRequest], filter: nil,
 progress: (init progress here), progressQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue(), completion: {
            _ in
        })
```

**NOT A DUPLICATE! Answer/question referenced is what lead to this feature being implemented** https://stackoverflow.com/a/33503205/5222077

Comment: What do you mean? Autocompletion in Xcode should fill in the parameters for you. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @JonShier I don't know how to define the parameter, autocomplete doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define it as you would any closure in Swift. You can give the captured parameters any names you want, or none using `_`, but you need to have 3. For instance:

```
ImageDownloader().downloadImage(URLRequest: "http://httpbin.org/image/png", progress: { (bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalExpectedBytesToRead) in
    print("Read:\(bytesRead), Total Read: \(totalBytesRead), Expected: \(totalExpectedBytesToRead)")
})
```